# How to collapse all character vectors in a list

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with one specific column that is made up of a list of characters as follows:

```
a <- list("dyspla", c("dyspla", "dyspla"), "carcin",
          c("tumour", "dyspla"), character(0), character(0),
          c("carcin", "dyspla"), character(0), character(0), "dyspla")
```

I want it to be a character vector with the character vectors in the list collapsed as follows

```
c("dyspla","dyspla,dyspla","carcin","tumour,dyspla","carcin,dyspla","dyspla")
```

`paste(a,collapse=" ")`  collapses everything together. How to collapse by vector within the list?

Comment: unlist(a) should do it.

Comment: @RicardoFernandesCampos Will that maintain empty character strings as well (as edited

Comment: @SebastianZeki try it and see!

Comment: Thanks @AdamO I did. It didn't work. That's why I asked.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't notice the edit. It will not.

Comment: @SebastianZeki oh I missed what you were asking for. I find `nonempty <- function(x) length(x) >0` to be a useful wrapper for all my functions. Here I would do: `sapply(Filter(nonempty, a), paste, collapse=',')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
sapply(a[!!lengths(a)], toString)
```

Or with `purrr`'s `is_empty` function:

```
sapply(a[!sapply(a, purrr::is_empty)], toString)
```

which both give:

> ```
> [1] "dyspla"         "dyspla, dyspla" "carcin"         "tumour, dyspla" "carcin, dyspla" "dyspla"
> ```

Alternatively with `paste`:

```
sapply(a[!sapply(a, purrr::is_empty)], paste, collapse = ',')
```

---

In response to your comment:

If you want to keep the empty character, you can just do `sapply(a, toString)` or `sapply(a, paste, collapse = ',')`.

Comment: I just realised the solution will not keep completely empty characters- see the character(0) in the question...

Comment: @SebastianZeki In the desired output as specified by you, the empty character are omitted. So does this solution. If you want to include the empty character, you can just do `sapply(a, toString)` or `sapply(a, paste, collapse = ',')`. Updated my answer with that as well.